# Concurrency issue with std::map insert/erase

Tags: c++, concurrency, pthreads

I'm writing a threaded application that will process a list of resources and may or may not place a resulting item in a container (std::map) for each resource.
The processing of resources takes place in multiple threads.

The result container will be traversed and each item acted upon by a seperate thread which takes an item and updates a MySQL database (using mysqlcppconn API), then removes the item from the container and continues.

For simplicities sake, here's the overview of the logic:

```
queueWorker() - thread
    getResourcesList() - seeds the global queue

databaseWorker() - thread
    commitProcessedResources() - commits results to a database every n seconds

processResources() - thread x <# of processor cores>
    processResource()
    queueResultItem()
```

And the pseudo-implementation to show what I'm doing.

```
/* not the actual stucts, but just for simplicities sake */
struct queue_item_t {
    int id;
    string hash;
    string text;
};

struct result_item_t {
    string hash; // hexadecimal sha1 digest
    int state;
}

std::map< string, queue_item_t > queue;
std::map< string, result_item_t > results;

bool processResource (queue_item_t *item)
{
    result_item_t result;

    if (some_stuff_that_doesnt_apply_to_all_resources)
    {
        result.hash = item->hash;
        result.state = 1;

        /* PROBLEM IS HERE */
        queueResultItem(result);
    }
}

void commitProcessedResources ()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&resultQueueMutex);

    // this can take a while since there

    for (std::map< string, result_item_t >::iterator it = results.begin; it != results.end();)
    {
        // do mysql stuff that takes a while

        results.erase(it++);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultQueueMutex);
}

void queueResultItem (result_item_t result)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&resultQueueMutex);

    results.insert(make_pair(result.hash, result));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultQueueMutex);
}
```

As indicated in processResource(), the problem is there and is that when commitProcessedResources() is running and resultQueueMutex is locked, we'll wait here for queueResultItem() to return since it'll try to lock the same mutex and therefore will wait until it's done, which might take a while.

Since there, obviously, is a limited number of threads running, as soon as all of them are waiting for queueResultItem() to finish, no more work will be done until the mutex is released and usable for queueResultItem().

**So, my question is how I best go about implementing this? Is there a specific kind of standard container that can be inserted into and deleted from simultaneously or does there exist something that I just don't know of?**

It is not *strictly* necessary that each queue item can have it's own unique key as is the case here with the std::map, but I would prefer it since several resources can produce the same result and I would prefer to only send a unique result to the database even if it *does* use INSERT IGNORE to ignore any duplicates.

I'm fairly new to C++ so I've no idea what to look for on Google, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to hold the lock for the queue all the time during processing in `commitProcessedResources ()`. You can instead swap the queue with empty one:

```
void commitProcessedResources ()
{
    std::map< string, result_item_t > queue2;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&resultQueueMutex);
    // XXX Do a quick swap.
    queue2.swap (results);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultQueueMutex);

    // this can take a while since there

    for (std::map< string, result_item_t >::iterator it = queue2.begin();
        it != queue2.end();)
    {
        // do mysql stuff that takes a while

        // XXX You do not need this.
        //results.erase(it++);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This seems to work quite well. I tried earlier to just assign:
    queue2 = results;
as i read somewhere that that will make a copy of 'results', but that didn't work.

Comment: @ThomasDaugaard: `queue2=results` will copy `results` to `queue2` but will not erase `results`. It is easier and faster to just swap empty queue with full one like I have shown.

Comment: Yeah, I know I need to .clear() the original, but as you say, this is far easier.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use synchronization methods (i.e. the mutex) to make this work properly. However, the goal of parallel programming is to minimize the critical section (i.e. the amount of code which is executed while you hold the lock).

That said, if your MySQL queries can be run in parallel without synchronization (i.e. multiple calls won't conflict with each other), take them out of the critical section. This will *greatly* reduce overhead. For instance, a simple refactor as follow could do the trick

```
void commitProcessedResources ()
{
    // MOVING THIS LOCK

    // this can take a while since there
    pthread_mutex_lock(&resultQueueMutex);
    std::map<string, result_item_t>::iterator end = results.end();
    std::map<string, result_item_t>::iterator begin = results.begin();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultQueueMutex);

    for (std::map< string, result_item_t >::iterator it = begin; it != end;)
    {
        // do mysql stuff that takes a while

        pthread_mutex_lock(&resultQueueMutex); // Is this the only place we need it?
        // This is a MUCH smaller critical section
        results.erase(it++);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultQueueMutex); // Unlock or everything will block until end of loop
    }

    // MOVED UNLOCK
}
```

This will give you concurrent "real-time" access to the data across multiple threads. That is, as every write finishes, the map is updated and can be read elsewhere with current information.

Comment: My only question here is, if results.end() will be reevaluated on each iteration, and as items are added by the queueResultItem(), will that extend the loop until it's *completely* empty?

Comment: This, I believe, depends on how the compiler may optimize your code. In any event, view my updated solution for a small change to account for this.

Comment: @RageD: You still cannot execute `results.begin()` without the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Up through C++03, the standard didn't define anything about threading or thread safety at all (and since you're using `pthread`s, I'm guess that's pretty much what you're using).

As such, it's up to you to do locking on your shared map, to ensure that only one thread tries to access the map at any given time. Without that, you're likely to corrupt its internal data structure, so the map is no longer valid at all.

Alternatively (and I'd generally prefer this) you could have your multiple thread just put their data into a thread-safe queue, and have a single thread that gets data from that queue and puts it into the map. Since it's single-threaded, you no longer have to lock the map when its in use.

There are a few reasonable possibilities for dealing with the delay while you flush the map to the disk. Probably the simplest is to have the same thread read from the queue, insert into the map, and periodically flush the map to disk. In this case, the incoming data just sits in the queue while the map is being flushed to disk. This keeps access to the map simple -- since only one thread ever touches it directly, it can use the map without any locking.

Another would be to have two maps. At any given time, the thread that flushes to disk gets one map, and the thread the retrieves from the queue and inserts into the map gets the other. When the flushing thread needs to do its thing, it just swaps the roles of the two.  Personally, I think I prefer the first though -- eliminating all the locking around the map has a great deal of appeal, at least to me.

Yet another variant that would maintain that simplicity would be for the queue->map thread to create map, fill it, and when it's full enough (i.e., after the appropriate length of time) stuff it into another queue, then repeat from the start (i.e., create new map, etc.) The flushing thread retrieves a map from its incoming queue, flushes it to disk, and destroys it. Though this adds a bit of overhead creating and destroying maps, you're not doing it often enough to care a lot. You still keep single-threaded access to any map at any time, and still keep all the database access segregated from everything else.